# How to draw a polygon around NA values in R?

Tags: r, na

I'm trying to draw an error region around my data using base graphics. I've figured out how to do it with a polygon, but it starts to act up really badly if there are any `NA` values in my data.

```
dat <- rnorm(10, mean = 1:10)
depth <- 11:20
sd <- rnorm(10, mean = 1.5, sd = 0.5)
col <- "blue"
alpha <- .2

col <- adjustcolor(col, alpha.f = alpha)
par(mfrow = c(1,2))
plot(dat, depth, type = "o", main = "No NAs in dat or depth")
x <- c(dat - sd, rev(dat + sd))
y <- c(depth, rev(depth))
polygon(x = x, y = y, col = col, border = NA)

dat[7] <- NA
plot(dat, depth, type = "o", main = "NAs in dat or depth")
x <- c(dat - sd, rev(dat + sd))
y <- c(depth, rev(depth))

polygon(x = x, y = y, col = col, border = NA)
```

This gives me the following image:
[image: The desired outcome if there are no NAs (left panel) and the error I get when there are NAs (right panel)]

It seems like the NA value divides the lower polygon into two polygons. What I'd like it to do is keep it as one polygon.

Comment: Simplest solution is using `na.omit`, but not sure if that's what you're after.

Comment: No, i'd prefer it if I could still see which regions have no data (i.e., draw no line between those points). But thanks!

Comment: The single NA in dat ends up as two NAs in x (because x goes down and up again). This means you'll now get three polygons because there's now three parts (divided by two NAs). You need a different way to rearrange the x and y at the breaks...

Comment: Would you like a ggplot2 solution? Because `geom_ribbon` makes it trivial, and expands the x-axis to fit it all in automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a possible solution using [`rle`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/rle.html) function:

```
set.seed(123) # added for reproducibility
dat <- rnorm(10, mean = 1:10)
depth <- 11:20
sd <- rnorm(10, mean = 1.5, sd = 0.5)
col <- "blue"
alpha <- .2

col <- adjustcolor(col, alpha.f = alpha)
par(mfrow = c(1,2))
plot(dat, depth, type = "o", main = "No NAs in dat or depth")
x <- c(dat - sd, rev(dat + sd))
y <- c(depth, rev(depth))
polygon(x = x, y = y, col = col, border = NA)

dat[7] <- NA
plot(dat, depth, type = "o", main = "NAs in dat or depth")
x <- c(dat - sd, rev(dat + sd))
y <- c(depth, rev(depth))

############################################
## code to print error range starts here: ##
############################################
enc <- rle(!is.na(dat))
endIdxs <- cumsum(enc$lengths)
for(i in 1:length(enc$lengths)){
  if(enc$values[i]){
    endIdx <- endIdxs[i]
    startIdx <- endIdx - enc$lengths[i] + 1

    subdat <- dat[startIdx:endIdx]
    subsd <- sd[startIdx:endIdx]
    subdepth <- depth[startIdx:endIdx]

    x <- c(subdat - subsd, rev(subdat + subsd))
    y <- c(subdepth, rev(subdepth))

    polygon(x = x, y = y, col = col, border = NA)
  }
}
```

[image]

The idea is to plot one polygon for each consecutive non-NA block.

Since `rle`, given a vector, returns the lengths and the values of the consecutive blocks having the same value, we use it to identify the blocks which are not NA and plot a polygon subsetting the original `dat`, `depth` and `sd` vectors.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

Is this acceptable?

```
polygon(x = x[!is.na(x)], y = y[!is.na(x)], col = col, border = NA)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for answering! While it is simple I prefer the other solution because now it seems that there is an error bar available between the values adjacent to the NA.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to try `ggplot2` solutions, here's this:

Put sample data in a data frame and add columns for low and high (after setting one data point to `NA`):

```
> d=data.frame(dat=dat, depth=depth)
> d$dat[7]=NA
> d$high=d$dat+sd
> d$low=d$dat-sd
```

Then its a one-liner:

```
> require(ggplot2)
> ggplot(d,aes(x=depth,y=dat)) + 
    geom_ribbon(aes(ymax=high,ymin=low),
                fill=adjustcolor("blue",.2) ) +
    geom_line() + 
    geom_point() + 
    coord_flip()
```

[image: flipped ribbon]

Comment: Thanks for answering! I am plugging this little piece of code into my already existing "plotting function" that uses base graphics, so unfortunately this doesn't help much. I've never seriously looked into using ggplot2 yet ;).